# Opening links outside the iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar within an iframe in Drupal:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<base target="_blank">
</head>

<body>
<div class="embed-container">
    <iframe width="700" height="700" src="../../../Kalender/index.html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

This works as I expected. However links, which are attached to the event, open in the same calender iframe. I would like to open them outside the iframe. Unfortunately i have no direct URL (I only see it when I mouse over the event). Is there any way to escape the iframe?

Comment: thanks for the link. Already found and tried it, but it still opens within the iframe.

Comment: It’s probably because the iframe is not on the same domain as the pages itself.

Comment: It's running on a subdomain (sub.domain.tld) but I think that shouldn't matter. Even a link to sub.domain.tld opens in the same iframe.